# Heterogeneous treatment effects with two post-treatment time and without never-treated groups

Tags: econometrics, difference-in-difference, causality, heterogeneity

I am trying to evaluate a policy with staggered policy time (the policy was implemented in two different years), and there are no never-treated groups. The data (four-time period, highly unbalanced - Goodman Bacon's decomposition cannot be used) have two post-treatment times for early adopters and one for later adopters. Since traditional two-way fixed effect (DID) can be biased because of the varying implementation time and policy heterogeneity, I am trying to implement some most recently proposed alternative estimators for DID models, such as [Sun and Abraham, 2021](https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/econom/v225y2021i2p175-199.html) and [Callaway and Santa'Anna, 2020](https://ideas.repec.org/a/eee/econom/v225y2021i2p200-230.html). However, these models drop the last time period (to have a control group) and the year prior to the policy (collinearity) therefore the estimated effects would only reflect the policy effects for early adopters (based on my understanding). Are the results from these estimators still justifiable? Does it make sense if I set the two groups as controls separately and assess the estimated policy effects on the other groups?  Any other ways to check the seriousness of negative weights? Any suggestions or comments are much welcome as I am still learning these methods! Many thanks!

p.s. All analysis is done in R (*did* and *fixest* package).